# Trying to Understand ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am getting a Value Error: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value. I am assuming that this means that there is an issue with the value I am attempting to use as an index. This is the error:

```
  File "/MyFile.py", line 900, in myProblematicFunction
self.data[reqId].loc[pd.to_datetime(time, unit='s')] = [some fields]
  File "/.conda/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 670, in __setitem__
iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "/.conda/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1802, in _setitem_with_indexer
self.obj._mgr = self.obj._mgr.setitem(indexer=indexer, value=value)
  File '/.conda/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 534, in setitem
return self.apply("setitem", indexer=indexer, value=value)
  File "/.conda/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 406, in apply
applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/.conda/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 855, in setitem
check_setitem_lengths(indexer, value, values)
  File "/.conda/envs/untitled/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexers.py", line 161, in check_setitem_lengths
"cannot set using a slice indexer with a "
ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value
```

From my understanding the problem is occurring here and the problem is with the variable time (this is a data frame in a dict):

```
self.data[reqId].loc[pd.to_datetime(time, unit='s')] = [some fields]
```

I have no control of the data that is flowing into the variable time, but I would like to catch whether the value of this variable is not appropriate prior to proceeding to this step. I guess I'm not completely sure what is going on with the time I am receiving for it to cause an issue. Any ideas on how it would be best to troubleshoot?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do read the guideline for posting questions. As a rule, if you share code, also share the data associated to it so the community may try to backtrack the error. Have you tried replacing ```=``` with ```==```

Comment: As I said, I have no control of the data flowing into the data frame. The data is streamed through an API so I don't have the data that is causing the problem. The line with the equal sign takes the data received through the API and inserts it into a data frame using the time variable as an index. Every so often something goes wrong at this step but I don't really understand what in order to be able to catch it before it errors. So i was hoping for someone to give me an ides of why you might get this error... I've searched but I couldn't find any good explanation for it

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is, you're attempting to slice the dataframe with a certain amount of fields, and then trying to set the values in that slice using a different number of values. Beyond that, we can't help if we don't know what `data[reqId].loc[pd.to_datetime(time, unit='s')]` and `[some fields]` look like when the error occurs

Comment: I have no idea what values look like either when problem occurs (which is infrequent but id like to fix it). some fields = [id, a, b, c, d, e, c*d]. Which are # values that are received (streaming tick data). My guess is either there is a problem with time or c*d is an issue if nans received(?). I tried printing values before putting them in df but since values arrive few times per sec, this isn't helpful since they continue arriving after problem occurs and I just end up with a wall of #s. maybe i can try checking if each of the values is a # or if it exists prior to trying to put them in df

Comment: Seems like the best way to diagnose the issue is to enable or create some sort of logging to check values